# Rounding columns in a dataframe with file.dtypes.iteritems()

Tags: python, decimal, rounding

I'm making a function on rounding decimals, I wrote the following already:

```
for colname, coltype in file.dtypes.iteritems():
    if coltype in lst:
        file[colname] = file[colname].round(desired_decimals)
```

However, it does not round the columns it should round.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two files are created, the values are written in the first in their own format, in the second in a string format.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[5.291752, 8.920429, 10.0]})

pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.6f}'.format

df.to_csv('string_no.csv', index=False, header=['A'])

with open('string_yes.csv', 'w') as file:
    file.writelines(df.to_string(index=False, header=['A']))
```

Output ordinary

[image]

Output string format

[image]

Comment: Somehow this still does not work within a for loop... When I return the "updated file" it still contains the original numbers

Comment: 'file' this is a dataframe? Can show some rows of your data?

Comment: File is indeed a dataframe, the rows are just floating-point numbers which all contain 6 decimals: 5.292000, 8.920000, 10.000000

Comment: @IrisJacobs Updated the message below. Probably, the problem is in the writing to the file itself.

Comment: @IrisJacobs The list that you have shown what is the expected result for it. I think I've figured out what the problem is. In the data frame, zeros are automatically remove and, for example, 5.292000 becomes 5.292. If zero are needed at the end after rounding, than this can be done by df.applymap('{:0<8}'. format), boot the column type will change.

Comment: Ah yes I indeed found the issue, because I first converted all numbers to 6 decimals with pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.6f}'.format, it keeps it zero's. Do you perhaps know a way in which I can convert all columns in the dataframe to 6 decimals without pandas keeping 6 decimals everywhere?

Comment: Another option would be to delete all columns with less than 6 decimals but I could not find a way to do this either

Comment: 1.In the print cycle, the numbers are output correct, as I understand it? 2.How many decimal places of the numbers do you want? 3.And finally, what is the type of one of the columns print(df['A'].type) replace the name 'A' of the column() and dataframe df with your own? 

Or let's do it easier. You can just show what you have in the dataframe and what you want to write to the file(what it looks like).

Comment: This is an excerpt of a row of the original dataframe: 5.291752 8.920429 10.0 and I want it to either become 5.291752 8.920429 10.000000 within the actual csv file or to completely remove the column that has 10.0  values (all columns with at least one value < 6 decimals should then be removed)

Comment: Most likely, when writing to a file, zeros are lost. So you need to write a string, then the zeros will not be lost. apply df = df.to_string() to your dataframe.

Comment: Someone suggested the following: df.to_csv(filepath, index=False, float_format='%.6f'), I'll see if this works

Comment: Replied to you in an updated message. Yes, indeed, zeros are lost when writing. Therefore, you need to write the values in string format. It is possible that there are other ways in pandas.
If you immediately showed your data and indicated what you specifically want, then it was done much faster)